# Complexity of algorithms other than asymptotic (Big-O - notation)

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, complexity-theory

What are the mostly adopted concept, other than asymptotic complexity (Big-O notation), used to evaluate algorithms?

**Example**:

Supposing I have the following algorithm that calls a function, func, with complexity O(1). Then this algorithm would have complexity O(N1 x N2). But if I knew beforehand that N1 is limited [1,5] then the worst case complexity would be O(5 x N2) which, by definition, is also O(N2).

```
for i in range(N1):
    for j in range(N2):
        func(i,j)
```

In case I can come across a different implementation of this algorithm using a function func2, again with complexity O(1), but now using different outer loop range, N3. This algorithm would be expected to be O(N3 x N2). However, if I knew the range of N3 was [10,50], then the worst case complexity would be O(50 x N2) which is again O(N2).

```
for i in range(N3):
    for j in range(N2):
        func2(i,j)
```

**Question**:

So, this is a simple to demonstrate that asymptotic notation is useful but maybe is not the most suitable comparison method for some more specific cases. How can I compare these two algorithms? What are the most commonly adopted methods? Is using just the number of iterations required for the algorithm a technically rigorous metric?

Any recommended reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very large. Read about algorithm complexity and metrics.

Your problem is that even if you don't use Big-O (there are many others small-o Big-omega, small-omega, theta, etc) you will not be able to easily compare algorithms the way it seems you want! The main reason is that you must first clearly define what you want to measure, and this is not easy. In general, you don't want details. Why? Because we know that we can always linearly accelerate any algorithm (roughly said, specials cases not relevant here). So the multiplicative constant is not relevant.

Now, what you want is (neither worst-case, best-case or average-case) more a prediction function for the running time that is somehow related to an **exact complexity**. But even there, there are many pitfalls and traps. You may think that two algorithms that have exact complexity of, say, 3n+45 will run as fast on the same platform, but this may be false! If you don't define exactly what you count, then this may be false. One may use 3n multiplications and the other 3n additions (or more subtle mixing of), and running time of multiplication and addition is generally not the same. Worst, as architecture may use pipelines, prediction and others runtime optimizations this may drastically change the running time. Even the environment platform may introduce serious bias, think about virtual memory, caches, various compiler optimizations, etc.

So, the answer is: it depends on what you want to predict... This is why there are so many complexity measures.

Comment: I completely agree with you. Do you have any specific recommendation of references?

Comment: May be Knuth's writings is a best place to start? He discuss many of these aspects...